# Converting JSONObjects to JavaObjects using Jackson API. Issue while converting JSONArray to java objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

Am getting response from my service as JSONArray. I want to convert this JSONArray to JavaObjects ( using POJO class). Am using Jackson API for JSON to JavaObject conversion. I also written helper class for that conversion ( class name : JsonUtil ).

Please find my JSON response below that containing JSONObjects as well as JSONArray too.

```
[  
       {  
          "order_number":"1000123",
          "customer_name":"Johnson Controls - ISC"
          "order_items":[  
             {  
                "line_number":"1",
                "product_code":"YMPA0100|Base",
                "product_description":"YMPA0100",
                "line_id":"c435d1bf-f9d4-47e6-b867-cda612429a6f",
                "product_quantity":1
             },
             {  
                "line_number":"1",
                "product_code":"YMPA0100|Base",
                "product_description":"YMPA0100",
                "line_id":"c435d1bf-f9d4-47e6-b867-cda612429a6f",
                "product_quantity":2
             },
             {  
                "line_number":"1",
                "product_code":"YMPA0100|Base",
                "product_description":"YMPA0100",
                "line_id":"c435d1bf-f9d4-47e6-b867-cda612429a6f",
                "product_quantity":2
             }
          ],

       }
]
```

From this, am able to convert if `order_items` array is not presented. If `order_items` array is presented means it throws the below error.

> Error : Exception occured while converting JSON into Java ObjectsCan not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
>    at [Source: java.io.StringReader@3444d69d; line: 1, column: 352] (through reference chain: com.util.OrderHeader["order_items"])

Please find my client code below :

```
public class Demo {
    public static <Order> void main(String[] args)  {
        Client client = Client.getInstance();
        client.start();
        String findOrderString = 
        client.findOrder("","1000123",").toString();
        String result = findOrderString.replaceAll("[\\[\\] ]","");
        System.out.println("JsonString:::"+result);

        OrderHeader so=JsonUtil.convertJsonToJava(result, 
        OrderHeader.class);
      System.out.println("==>"+so.getCustomer_name()+",
      "+so.getOrder_number());
    }
```

`OrderHeader` POJO class:

```
public class OrderHeader {

    String order_number;
    String customer_name;

    List<OrderItem> order_items;
    //Setters & Getters method

}
```

`OrderItem` POJO class : ( which should be a JSONArray in `OrderHeader` POJO class )

```
public class OrderItem {

    String line_id;
    String line_number;
    String product_code;
    String product_description; 
    Long product_quantity;  

    //Getters & Setters method

}
```

Please find my helper class to conver JSON to JavaObject

```
public class JsonUtil {

    private static ObjectMapper mapper;
    static{
        mapper=new ObjectMapper();
    }


    public static <T> T convertJsonToJava(String jsonString, Class<T> cls)
    {
        T result=null;
        try {
            result=mapper.readValue(jsonString, cls);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured while converting JSON into 
            Java Objects"+e.getMessage());

        return result;

    }
}
```

Comment: `OrderHeader so = JsonUtil.convertJsonToJava(result, OrderHeader.class);`

This statement is trying to convert the json into OrderHeader object but the json is actually an array.

Comment: I don't know if it's just an error of paste but you have a , after "order_items" but no after "Customer_name"

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectMapper as below:

```
private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<Event> events = readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<Event>>() {});
```

of course, you'll need to wrap it in try catch block.